# Set value in dependency of Helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I want to use the [postgresql chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) as a requirements for my Helm chart.

My `requirements.yaml` file hence looks like this:

```
dependencies:
  - name: "postgresql"
    version: "3.10.0"
    repository: "@stable"
```

In the postgreSQL Helm chart I now want to set the username with the property `postgresqlUsername` (see https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql for all properties).

Where do I have to specify this property in my project so that it gets propagated to the postgreSQL dependency?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As described in https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#subcharts-and-global-values, in your parent (i.e. not the dependency) chart's `values.yaml` file, have a section that contains

```
postgresql:
  postgresUsername: ....
  postgresPassword: ....
  ...
```

That is, all values under the `postgresql` key will override the child (`postgresql`) chart's `values.yaml` values. Note that if you have aliased the `postgresql` dependency chart to another name in your `requirements.yaml`, you should use that other name instead of `postgresql`.

edit: The corresponding article in v3 is here https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/

Comment: There appears to be no way to use variables in this context, though. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4447

Comment: @jhanschoo OMG thank you for the link to docs. I stumbled upon the page several times, but for some reason i did not make it to the part where they rewrite the subchart values, before.

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md - 404 not found

Comment: Since the related docs links are down, I'll directly state the information that I was missing:

in this case, the project that's including 'postgres' as a dependency, the overriding 'values.yaml' has to prefix+indent them with 'postgres:' parent block, to define and/or override dependency's values inside it.