# Custom helm chart requires another stable/chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created a chart which requires a helm chart from [stable/charts](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable), lets say [mongodb](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb). Although you can define a [requirements.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_dependency_list.md) file I was wondering if it is possible to define a chart in here?

Furthermore, to make things easier (not) I need to replace some values for the mongodb chart as well. Not sure if I'm pushing the limits here to much :) It looks like a subchart relation, so it sounds possible.

The alternative, which I'm using now is to first install the stable/chart and then my custom chart. But it would be an improvement if I could reduce this to one `helm` command just by adding this dependency to my custom chart

**Update**:

I will update this post with my findings and hopefully this will eventually lead to the solution :) The `requirements.yaml` so far:

```
dependencies:
  - name: "mongodb"
    version: "4.x.x"
    repository: "@stable"
    import-values:
      - child: default.data
        parent: myimports
```

Not sure yet how I can use `import-values` to customize mongodb, but for now I'm stuck on the following error

```
Error: found in requirements.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: mongodb
```

Also, because I'm using `stable` I'm not sure what to do with the `version` field

Useful links: [link](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#using-the-child-parent-format), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748639/set-value-in-dependency-of-helm-chart)

Answer (score 2):

since helm 2.2.0, you can store the mongodb chart at the same directory and in your `requirements.yaml` file refer to it as:

```
dependencies:

- name: mongodb
  version: "<the_mongo_chart_version>"
  repository: "file://../mongodb"
```

thats way you can play with the values and deploy the whole thing with 1 helm command.

for more information refer to

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_dependency.md

Comment: I've updated my post, which is easier to define my findings than it is in a comment. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/docs/helm/helm_dependency.md - 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this not enough to add dependency charts into your requirements.yaml file.

Also, charts himself should be physically in charts directory. This is a helm limitation.

If you agree to manage a third party chart in your repo (should be pretty easy) then you be able to install all by one helm command and change subchart values as mentioned [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md).

I have an example elasticsearch and kibana installation as one chart: [In my test repo](https://github.com/ozlevka/environments-/tree/master/k8s/helmchart/test). Please review. I hope this example helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Handling 3rd party charts in your own repo might be the trivial solution since you need one helm command to run it, but it makes maintenance much more cumbersome.

I would go with defining the helm dependencies and then running a small script to download them just like any other package-management system would do, you can do it as following:

#### Defining

`requirements.yaml`

```
dependencies:
- name: "mongodb"
 version: "7.8.10" <--- Pay attention this refers to the chart's version and not the app version [see link 1]
    repository: "@stable"
```

1. https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/Chart.yaml#L3

#### Installing

run shell script that creates the charts folder and get the charts in the `requirements.yaml`

`install.sh`

```
helm dependencies list
helm dependencies update
helm install --name my-chart .
```

#### Passing values to sub-charts

in case you want to change the values of the sub-chart you need to follow the exact same path of the chart's value path (in this example `ingress.enabled`) and add the top level chart name.

Pay attention! this have to be an exact match to the chart name mentioned in the `requirements.yaml`!

There are two ways to set those values:

either with the command line:
`helm install --name my-chart . --set mongodb.ingress.enabled=true`
or inside your own `values.yaml`

```
mongodb:
  ingress:
    enabled: "true"
```