# How to set helm chart dependency parameters

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a helm chart that's dependent on the stable/postgres chart. I'm using helm version 2.14.

While specifying this dependency in the `requirements.yaml` file, I'd like to set some of the parameters such as `persistence.size` which are usually passed using `helm install --set`.

I tried to follow the instructions in this post: [Set value in dependency of Helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748639/set-value-in-dependency-of-helm-chart)

I added this at the end of my `values.yaml`:

```
postgresql:
  replication:
    enabled: true
    slaveReplicas: 2
  persistence:
    size: 2Gi
```

But unfortunately after `helm dep update`, I inspected the downloaded chart and the values in `values.yaml` were not overwritten.

What could be missing here or what are my alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: The `helm dependency` commands basically just download and unpack tar files; the subcharts' `values.yaml` files will never be changed directly.  If you run `helm template`, or deploy the chart and look at `helm get values`, you will see the parent-chart values overriding the subchart's.

Answer (score 3):

A parent chart can not overwrite values of subchart(s). Please refer to [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/):

> 1. A subchart is considered “stand-alone”, which means a subchart can never explicitly depend on its parent chart.

1. For that reason, a subchart cannot access the values of its parent.
2. A parent chart can override values for subcharts.

Your `values.yaml` in either parent chart or for your helm release will take effect when installing chart into k8s or render via `helm template`. However, `values.yaml` of a subchart will be kept as it was.