# Timezone in requirements.yaml to add dependency to a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, mariadb, kubernetes-helm

The helm chart we are using for a particular microservice has the following dependency:

```
dependencies:
- name: mariadb
  version: 7.x.x.
  repository: "abc"
  condition: mariadb.enabled
  tags:
    - database
```

When we login to the microservice pod, the timezone shown is local as configured in the deployment.
However, when we log into the mariadb pod, the timezone is in UTC.

Could someone help me understand how to set local timezone instead of UTC in mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

To change MardiaDB timezone you need to edit `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.conf`

```
# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]
default-time-zone=-06:00
```

The value is a string and you would need to figure out for your timezone to do so look up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

As for helm and [mariaDB chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb), I was unable to find any timezone parameters you can set while deploying the chart.

So you would need to download the [value.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/charts/master/stable/mariadb/values.yaml) from https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb

Edit the value.yaml file and add:

```
extraEnvVars:
   - name: TZ
     value: "UTC"
```

or any other TZ you like `Europe/Paris`.
Once done you can use the `value.yaml` in a following way:

```
$ helm install --name my-release stable/mariadb -f values.yaml
```

You can also read how to [set value in dependency of helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748639/set-value-in-dependency-of-helm-chart).